# wait until end of completion handler to return a BOOL?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a function that needs to wait for the outcome of a completion handler to return a BOOL for which the value will be set within a completion handler:

```
-(BOOL) fetchFeed
{
......
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
    [sharedSessionMainQueue dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:
     ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

                NSMutableArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
              options:0
              error:nil];


              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

              if(!jsonObject)
              {
                  UIAlertAction *ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){[self dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];}];

                  UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Connection problem." message:@"Please check your internet connection and trying logging in again." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                  [alert addAction:ok];
                  [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                  _internetFailed = YES;
              }
                  else
                  {
                      _internetFailed = NO;
                  }


              });

         }];

    [dataTask resume];
    return _internetFailed;

}
```

The problem is that right now _internetFailed is returned before the end of the completion handler. I tried moving the "return _internetFailed" into the completion handler, but that is disallowed. Question: how should I structure this so that the return waits for the end of the completion handler?

I looked around but could not find a completion handler within a completion handler type paradigm. What other options are there? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: You can use semaphore

Comment: @Andy thanks I did not even know those existed. Will look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, just because you don't have a `JSON` object doesn't mean the connection failed, you need to actually check the returned error for that information or run a `reachability` check. Or you could have just gotten invalid JSON or any number of other errors. So you need to check the error you're getting back before deciding what to present to the user.

Second, this method is declared `void` so returning a BOOL isn't a good idea. If you want to know the status of this task, put something in the completion block at the calling site. Normally, methods like this will just return the task directly and allow any other behavior to be handled in the completion.

Here's what it might look like:

```
-(NSURLSessionDataTask *)fetchFeedWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSArray *responseArray, NSError *error)completionBlock
{
    ....
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [sharedSessionMainQueue dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        //Check response status.
        //Check error.
        NSError *JSONError;
        NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&JSONError];
        if (completionBlock) { // Check the completion block before calling, as calling a nil block will crash.
            if (//Any error.) {
                competionBlock(nil, error);
            }
            else {
                completionBlock(responseArray, nil);
            }
        }
    }

    [dataTask resume];
    return dataTask;
}
```

Then, if this completion returned it error you could present the error at the calling site, like this:

```
[communicator fetchFeedWithCompletionBlock:^(NSArray *responseArray, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // Present error.
    }
    else {
       // Use array.
    }
}];
```

Also, as with any question with type I recommend at least perusing the source for [AFNetworking](http://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking) or using it directly.

Comment: Thank you for the info. The function is a BOOL - it was a typo above, but thanks for pointing that out as well.